# How to determine for how long a thread was stuck in crash?

Tags: linux-kernel, crash, crash-dumps

When inspecting a vmcore using crash tool, how to determine for how long a thread was stuck?

Here is an example:

How do I determine for how this thread has been waiting for the percpu reference counter to switch to atomic mode?

```
PID: 10637  TASK: ffffa035b3d0a080  CPU: 7   COMMAND: "md66_raid10"
 #0 [ffffa035b2363c08] __schedule at ffffffffb616ab17
 #1 [ffffa035b2363c90] schedule at ffffffffb616b019
 #2 [ffffa035b2363ca0] percpu_ref_switch_to_atomic_sync at ffffffffb5d7af15
 #3 [ffffa035b2363ce8] set_in_sync at ffffffffb5f8d6a7
 #4 [ffffa035b2363d10] md_check_recovery at ffffffffb5f95fd7
 #5 [ffffa035b2363d30] md_check_recovery at ffffffffb5f96368
 #6 [ffffa035b2363d40] raid10d at ffffffffc093bc45 [raid10]
 #7 [ffffa035b2363e50] md_thread at ffffffffb5f8cc3d
 #8 [ffffa035b2363ec8] kthread at ffffffffb5ac1f81
 #9 [ffffa035b2363f50] ret_from_fork_nospec_begin at ffffffffb6177c1d
```

Comment: Can you precisely define "stuck"?

Comment: @stark, I thought this was something easy to understand. waiting in a waitqueue might be one example.

Comment: I guess not easy for me.  In the stack you're showing md can wait on disk error recovery, `percpu_ref_switch` can wait on spinlock.  If the spinlock is the problem, you would need to build the kernel with spinlock instrumentation.  Any specific definition of "stuck" would require a different solution.

Comment: it is not a spinlock problem. it is something with the percpu reference counter not switching to atomic mode. It is a complex task and needs rcu calls and lots of asynchrony involved.

Comment: @stark, I do see lots of other threads which were waiting to acquire a spinlock. Would that affect the percpu ref counter? Also, I want to be able to tell something along the lines of this "thread was waiting on the percpu refcounter switch for 20 seconds". How can I do that?

Comment: On Windows, that's not possible. You can only check the CPU time of the thread in total.

Comment: And IMHO, a thread is never stuck in a crash. A crash will terminate the program. Maybe you want to replace crash by deadlock.